# What does "union down, at the main" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XIII, Published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_13)

Passage 206

> I climbed into the rigging, stood on the board, and eagerly scanned that ring of coral reef and bursting breaker, and the blue lagoon which they enclosed. The two islets within began to show plainly—Middle Brooks and Lower Brooks Island, the Directory named them: two low, bush-covered, rolling strips of sand, each with glittering beaches, each perhaps a mile or a mile and a half in length, running east and west, and divided by a narrow channel. Over these, innumerable as maggots, there hovered, chattered, screamed and clanged, millions of twinkling sea-birds: white and black; the black by far the largest. With singular scintillations, this vortex of winged life swayed to and fro in the strong sunshine, whirled continually through itself, and would now and again burst asunder and scatter as wide as the lagoon: so that I was irresistibly reminded of what I had read of nebular convulsions. A thin cloud overspread the area of the reef and the adjacent sea—the dust, as I could not but fancy, of earlier explosions. And a little apart, there was yet another focus of centrifugal and centripetal flight, where, hard by the deafening line of breakers, her sails (all but the tattered topsail) snugly furled down, and the red rag that marks Old England on the seas beating, **union down, at the main**—the Flying Scud, the fruit of so many toilers, a recollection in so many lives of men, whose tall spars had been mirrored in the remotest corners of the sea—lay stationary at last and forever, in the first stage of naval dissolution. Towards her, the taut Norah Creina, vulture-wise, wriggled to windward: come from so far to pick her bones. And, look as I pleased, there was no other presence of man or of man's handiwork; no Honolulu schooner lay there crowded with armed rivals, no smoke rose from the fire at which I fancied Trent cooking a meal of sea-birds. It seemed, after all, we were in time, and I drew a mighty breath.

What does "union down, at the main" mean in this context? What's meant by these 'easy' words - don't have any idea actually.

Comment: This is pretty complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_ensign the Union Jack [flag], at the main means at the mainsail. I reckon. So, my reading is: the red rag that marks Old England on the seas was beating (flapping?) at the mainsail. Maybe that.

Comment: [OED: **union down**](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/union_n2?tab=meaning_and_use#335939773) (also downwards): (of the hoisting or flying of a flag) upside down with the union (sense IV.18) in the lower corner, as a sign of distress or mourning. So far as I know, that actual expression normally only applies to the American flag. British ships also fly the "Union Jack" upside down, but the *entire* flag is "the union" (unlike the American flag, where the bit with the stars symbolises the union of the United States, or the Australian flag, which has a British union jack in the top corner)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - see my answer below; the Red and Blue Ensigns have a reduced Union Flag in the upper hoist quadrant, and this is called the Union as well.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I'm *not* reading the book, so I don't really care. If I *was* reading it, I'd probably know the nationalities of any ships mentioned by name. But all I need to know is "upside-down flag = distress signal" (i.e. - "Please help!", as opposed to flag flying at half-mast = "in mourning"). But even if I was right up close to it (or at sea, if I had a *very* good telescope! :), I wouldn't know if the Union Jack was upside down. And I certainly don't intend to waste any of my remaining brain cells looking up and remembering the correct positions of the thick and thin lines!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Look up "red ensign" and "blue ensign". It's not talking about flying the Union Flag upside-down.

Comment: The context appears to be a ship flying a flag upside down (or at half-mast, it's all one to me), because that ship is being decommissioned. It makes no difference to me *which* flag it's flying. But I will say that apparently *the Clipper Ship “**Flying Scud**” [was sold at London, in April 1863](https://pickeringhistory.com/flying-scud/), and became the British ship **Cestrian**, of Liverpool.* So obviously it *wasn't* decommissioned while it was still called Flying Scud - but again, I don't know or care exactly what year the cited text refers to. Or whether it's historically accurate.

Comment: I would hope that the OP realised this was something to do with a flag, in which case it would make more sense to ask in History SE where there are more vexillologists. Maybe the OP knew it was about flags but didn't know which flags, maybe the OP doesn't know ships fly flags or what a ship is, this is why you are supposed to say what you have done to solve your problem, how much you understand, and what you have found out so far.

Comment: Partly answerable by using a dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/union%20down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a bit of vexillological terminology: When a flag is flying normally, the part that is closest to the flagpole (or mast, on ships) is called “the hoist”; the part that is free to flap in the wind is called “the fly”.

British flags on ships (*ensigns*) are a solid color (generally red or blue) with a reduced replica of the familiar [Union Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg) in the upper part of the hoist (and which is called the Union). The “red rag that marks Old England” is the [red ensign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Ensign#/media/File:Civil_Ensign_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg), and when it is flown as a sign of distress, the flag is inverted - that is, ***union down***.

(*The stars of the United States flag are also called the Union, and when a US ship is in distress, it also flies its flag ‘union down’*)

“at the main” refers to the ‘mainmast’ of the ship; see Wikipedia on [***full-rigged ships***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-rigged_ship) for more information.

Comment: The red ensign is usually flown close to the stern. Is it part of the distress signal to flyit at the mainmast?

Comment: Flag-flying practices, including the flying of ensigns, may have changed over time. Or RLS may not have been entirely familiar with the rules, or he may have written it that way as literary license.

Comment: The red ensign was required to be flown from the stern from 1864 (when the design was standardised) so you may be right, or perhaps the book is set at an earlier time.

Comment: There are signal flags which can describe the ship's situation in more detail. Perhaps in an emergency when there isn't time to run up a sequence of signal flags, they also hang the red ensign in the 'wrong' place to attract better attention. As @FumbleFingers commented, being inverted may not be immediately noticeable (although, the union part is in the hoist corner, so it's not just about detecting thick/thin lines).

Comment: The novel seems to have been set in the late 19th century, possibly the 1880s, based on Stevenson's own experiences at the time and locations in then-new ports such as Midway. But I don't think Treasure Island is terribly accurate either.

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting that very few people today would understand the words, "union down" or "at the main".